# Pass javascript variable to url parameter

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, url

I want to pass javascript string variables and render them on the URL.

For example, if I have URL = "xyc.com". Once there is a variable (a) populated, I want that variable to be rendered in the address bar with URL = "xyc.com/?a=" .

I am currently using the flask and .ajax function in javascript (where the variable is being populated) in this application. Can someone please provide me some guidance on how I can accomplish this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the URL without reloading the page

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, new_url);
```

If you want to reload the page with your new URL

```
window.location.href = new_url
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for replacing the URL:

```html
<label>
  End URL<input type='text' onInput='modURL()' id='append'>
<label>
<script>
  let url = location.href;
  localStorage.setItem("url",url);
  function modURL() {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {

      let newURL = localStorage.getItem("url")+'?q='+document.getElementById('append').value;
      let title = document.getElementById('append').value;
      let obj = { Title: title, Url: newURL };

      console.log("url ", newURL);
      history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    } else {
      alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Try it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eau20f1n/)