# Where can I try an my code with an input that actually replaces the search bar value?

Tags: javascript, html, url, pushstate

I have this code that is like the Netflix browser search function:

```js
let url = location.href;
  localStorage.setItem("url",url);
    function modURL() {
      if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        //get the url
        let newURL = localStorage.getItem("url")+'/?q='+document.getElementById('append').value;
        let title = document.getElementById('append').value;
        let obj = { Title: title, Url: newURL };

        console.log("url ", newURL);
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
      } else {
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
      }
    }
```

```html
<label>
  End URL<input type='text' onInput='modURL()' id='append'>
<label>
```

which I wanted to test to see if it actually replaces the URL. I tried on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eau20f1n/), the logs are outputting the correct URL, but is there an online editor that lets you replace the search bar?

Comment: You can't fire up a local server on your computer?

Comment: @JohnTyner. I could. And I have. I tried on a django server real quick. It worked on a template. But I was trying to avoid a local development. Anyway put it up as an answer, let me upvote.

Comment: How come you're trying to avoid local deployment out of curiosity

Comment: I got lazy. I was doing this in the first place out of curiosity and to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67411408/12415287) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67411276/12415287) as well.

Comment: It would still be nice to know if there is an online editor capable of handling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackblitz does the job pretty well. See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-u6e1wg?file=index.html)